# How to unzip a multipart (spanned) ZIP on Linux?

Tags: archive, zip

I need to upload a 400mb file to my web server, but I'm limited to 200mb uploads. My host suggested I use a spanned archive, which I've never done on Linux.

I created a test in its own folder, zipping up a PDF into `test.zip.001`, `.002`, and `.003`. How do I go about unzipping it? Do I need to join them first?

Please note that I'd be just as happy using 7z as I am using ZIP formats.  If this makes any difference to the outcome.

Comment: This may not be helpful on a web server with limited software installed, but I haven't seen this solution anywhere else and it's what I use: The java.util.zip API has dealt with all the ZIP parts I've thrown at it, even in the more general case of not having trailing parts or the last part being incomplete. I call it from Jython so it's in the form of a script, and here is the code: https://github.com/combatopera/unzipparts

Answer (score 164, accepted):

You will need to join them first. You may use the common linux app, `cat` as in the example below:

```
cat test.zip* > ~/test.zip
```

This will concatenate all of your `test.zip.001`, `test.zip.002`, etc files into one larger, test.zip file. Once you have that single file, you may run `unzip test.zip`

["How to create, split, join and extract zip archives in Linux"](http://linuxg.net/how-to-create-split-join-and-extract-zip-archives-in-linux) may help.

Comment: OK, I like that... Progress... But I really am a Linux n00b here. I assume `x*` is the filename? And `~/hugefile` is a directory? What is the purpose of the tilde symbol? Sorry to ask what I suspect are very basic questions.

Comment: when you split the files, you should use a prefix like x_ (ex: x_split1 , x_split2 , ... ; like the windows suffixes file.001, file.002...etc) the tilde represents your home directory. ~/hugefile is the same as /home/tim/hugefile. did you split your files ? what are the split files names?

Comment: I think I see where the issue will come in, the Spanned archive was created in windows, using 7zip with a ZIP extension, so it auto creates as `TEST.zip.001`, `TEST.zip.002` and `TEST.zip.003` which means the split is very different.  It's starting to look like it may be easier to thrown linux on a VMWare and create the files here, then at least i'm only dealing with 1 OS.

Can you use the SPLIT command on ANY file type?  i.e. images, audio movies etc?

Comment: yes, the split command works on any file. install p7zip with apt-get install p7zip on debian or yum install p7zip on fedora, join the files with: cat TEST.zip.* > archive and extract them with.

Comment: extract with $ 7za e archive

Comment: Can `CAT` be used on files other than `txt` files?

Comment: yes. you can join other files than txt files with cat.

Comment: `7za x archive` is probably better if the archive contains a directory structure.

Comment: Note that this doesnt work when having more than 10 files, because they will be sorted in the wrong order:
`
file1
file10
file2
`

To preserve ordering on large number of files, use:
`find ./ -name "*.zip.*" | sort -V | xargs cat > full.zip`

Comment: 7za e archive works. Thanks @fromnaboo

Answer (score 72):

The Linux `unzip` utility doesn't really support multipart zips. From the [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/unzip.1.html#contenttoc11):

> Multi-part  archives  are not yet supported, except in conjunction with zip.  (All parts must be concatenated together in order, and then `zip -F`  (for  zip  2.x) or `zip -FF` (for zip 3.x) must be performed on the concatenated archive in order to “fix” it.   Also,  zip  3.0  and later  can  combine multi-part (split) archives into a combined single-file archive using `zip -s- inarchive -O outarchive`. See the [zip 3 manual  page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/zip.1.html) for more information.)

So you need to first concatenate the pieces, then repair the result. `cat test.zip.*` concatenates all the files called `test.zip.*` where the wildcard `*` stands for any sequence of characters; the files are enumerated in lexicographic order, which is the same as numerical order thanks to the leadings zeroes. `>test.zip` directs the output into the file `test.zip`.

```
cat test.zip.* >test.zip
zip -FF test.zip --out test-full.zip
unzip test-full.zip
```

If you created the pieces by directly splitting the zip file, as opposed to creating a multi-part zip with the official Pkzip utility, all you need to do is join the parts.

```
cat test.zip.* >test.zip
unzip test.zip
```

Comment: the 2nd command should be zip -FF test.zip --out test-full.zip  --  will give you an error without the --out command

Comment: For me, the `FF` approach worked if I pointed `zip` to the first multi-part file, no `cat` needed.

Comment: As @JānisElmeris already mentioned, no need to concatenate the archives before using `zip -FF` on them.

Comment: with zip 3.0, ```zip -s- inarchive -O outarchive``` works as expected.

Comment: this worked for me as one of my projects is hosted on a shared hosting server, I cannot install 7zip or other utilities.

Comment: @JānisElmeris Not for me.

Answer (score 64):

```
7z x archive.zip.001
```

It will automatically find the rest

Comment: That's so weird... For this to work, you first need to rename all ZIP files (.zXX and .zip) to .zip.xxx (.zip is the last part), then you can use 7z x on the first one, which "extracts" to a concatenated zip which can then again be decompressed using unzip but not 7z... I'm not entirely sure if the file has been unpacked correctly but at least this time unzip does not complan about CRC errors... ZIP is so incredibly broken on Linux - avoid if you can. :(

Comment: at least for centos, we also need instruction how to install 7z

Comment: @Energiequant If you already used 7zip to create multipart, you do not need to rename files in this format.

Comment: Worked perfectly for a multi-part zip made by keka mac app!

Answer (score 32):

I found the answer here: https://superuser.com/a/517758/10264

This answer is similar in concept to that of [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40565/13676), namely first you combine the split archive into a normal archive using split, and then you unpack it using unzip.

The difference is that instead of using the `-FF` flag, which did not work for me, you just tell zip to repack the split file without splitting. That is what the `-s 0` flag means in the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip).

> A split archive can also be converted into a single-file archive using a split size of 0: `zip -s 0 test.zip -O single.zip`

So, first, combine the split archive to a single archive:

```bsh
zip -s 0 split-foo.zip --out unsplit-foo.zip
```

Then, extract the single archive using unzip:

```bsh
unzip unsplit-foo.zip
```

This approach only works for `.z01`, `.z02`, ..., `.zip` file structure. If your filenames are `.zip.001`, `.zip.002`..., you have rename them first using (e.g.) `rename zip.0 z test.zip*` with [rename](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rename).

Comment: This is the correct answer for zip 3.x

Comment: it works for me

Comment: In my case this corrupts some output files, or even fails. Seems it’s because it’s too big (30 files of 100MB). Well… the zip command-line tools haven’t had a release in more than 10 years (even though they get patched by distros since there were several vulnerabilities). I think from now on I will consider these tools as broken, and use 7zip instead.

Answer (score 14):

I think it's worth mentioning that the unar command-line tool is able to unZip, unRar, un7zip, unTar etc, including splitted files, with just:

```
unar first_file
```

https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Unar#Details

Comment: underrated comment: i've tried so many variations of the other answers that didn't work, using `unar` is a game-changer!

Comment: It also comes with `lsar` command. Do `lsar first_file` to list the content of the files (and maybe test incompleteness in multipart files)

Comment: just a note, this will probably work on Ubuntu only

Comment: on debian I get random `Archive parsing failed! (Unknown error.)` errors. WinRAR 5.0 on Windows can extract the *.001 files perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me on Ubuntu 18.04.

- split the compressed file into multiple archives, each is less than 1024MB

  ```bsh
  zip -s 1024m -r target.zip target/
  ```
- get the files: `target.z01`, `target.z02`, ..., `target.zip`
- before unzip them, combine them into one whole zip file

  ```bsh
  zip -FF target.zip --out target-full.zip
  unzip target-full.zip
  ```
- remove all the .z* file

  ```bsh
  rm *.z*
  ```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note, though, that it is rather similar in content [this answer by @Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40565/377345). Therefore, please consider editing your post to make the difference in your approach more visible. Also, you write "before unzip them, combine them into one whole zip file", but the instructions on how to do so seem to be incomplete (what happened to `target.z01` etc.?).

Comment: This line `zip -FF target.zip --out target-full.zip` will dump all the `target.z*` files into the `target-full.zip`. And it does not need to explicitly write something for `target.z01` etc.

Answer (score 2):

For a multipart zip coming from a Google Drive download I tried several of the explained methods but didn't work (well). I could finally do it in a simple way from the terminal:
unzip filename.zip.001
when finished extracting the same with the next part:
unzip filename.zip.002
and so on ...

Another option:
7z x filename.zip.001
when finished extracting the same with the next part:
7z x filename.zip.002
and so on ...

Comment: Yep. I think Google Drive zip files are not a split multi-part zip. They are just independent zip files!

Answer (score 1):

Note that some of the answers will not work as expected when having more than 10 files, because they will be sorted in the wrong order (alphabetical instead of numerical):

`file1 file10 file2`

To preserve ordering on large number of files, use:

`find ./ -name "*.zip.*" | sort -V | xargs cat > full.zip`

Answer (score 0):

Just another example. This worked for me in bash to split 3GB oracle installer:

```
echo "<installOracleDB.sh>: Splitting OracleDB installer"
zip /tmp/linuxx64_12201_database.zip --out /tmp/linuxx64_12201_oradb.zip -s 1000m
echo "<installOracleDB.sh>: Merging OracleDB installer"
zip -FF /tmp/linuxx64_12201_oradb.zip --out /tmp/linuxx64_12201_database.zip
echo "<installOracleDB.sh>: Removing temporary files OracleDB installer"
find /tmp -type f -name 'linuxx64_12201_oradb*' -exec rm {} +
echo "<installOracleDB.sh>: Unizipping OracleDB installer"
unzip /tmp/linuxx64_12201_database.zip
```

Comment: This looks very similar to previous answers. Can you explain what it is doing, and how it differs from what’s already been posted? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Hi Scot, i wish i could answer in the comments but i have to little points to do that right now. This answer gives a complete list of commands to split, merge and unzip a large file on unix. I will provide more explaining text to clarify my answer. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large collection of files or just very big files this command assembly is is pretty handy as it gets you a progress bar:

```
 $ pv files.zip* | cat - > uberFile.zip
 25.0GiB 0:50:24 [8.48MiB/s] [============================================================>] 100%
 $ unzip uberFile.zip
```

Just used this to combine and extract a 25Gb split archive.