# Installing Fedora on Mac with T2 security chip

Tags: fedora, macintosh

I am following the rabbit hole of instructions that begins at T2Linux.org for installing linux on a mac air.  It directs me to a github for getting the iso.

[image]

Will I need all six of the files or just the ones for kde if I want to use plasma?

I also tried to use cat to join the files as was suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40480/how-to-unzip-a-multipart-spanned-zip-on-linux)  Only the two files ending in .zip combined into the resulting file. I was using Ubuntu to join the files but am open to using windows or mac as well.